# Using JSON data to filll "columns" in datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am getting JSON data via AJAX and my data are in a result object. The fields of which can be accessed as in success: function(result)

```
result.map.count[0].name
result.map.count[0].count
```

I would like to show `name` and `count` as two columns of my datatable.

My ajax request is written as

```
table = $('#_table').dataTable({
                searching: false,
                paging: true,
                ajax: function (data, callback, settings) {
                    $.ajax({
                             type: "post",
                             url: '/test/getvalues',
                             dataType: "json",
                             success: function (result) {
                                 I am able to get data as "result" here
                                 result.map.count[0].name
                                 result.map.count[0].count
                             }
                           });
                  },
               columns: []
        })
```

what should I put in columns[] to show these fields?

```
columns: []
```

Comment: what is the data you are getting from result.object, can you update your question with that.

Comment: it's an object. result.map.count. count is an array with 10 elements you can access it as result.map.count[0] etc. In each element, there is result.map.count[0].name and result.map.count[0].count

Comment: @carpediumac can you please add your datatable code snippets?

Comment: @Allen Haley I just added the datatable snippet

Comment: @saladham, I added answer for you. Please try it.

Answer (score 0):

In your datatable configuration,add the following

```
 data: [[result.map.count.name,result.map.count.count]], // make it as array of values
     columns: [
                {
                 "sClass": "center",
                 "name": "Name"
                },
                {
                 "sClass": "center",
                 "name": "Count"
                },
            ]
```

Please check here for more details
https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html

Comment: I just updated my question on "result". I don't think your solution works. Sorry that is my bad!

Comment: @chandu komati it says result is undefined. I think the "result" object is only accessible in the "success" function because that's where I defined it. Everywhere else should be out of scope

Comment: yes you have to call the datatable inside the success function

Comment: https://www.phpflow.com/php/datatables-example-server-side-processing-with-php/
check it. syntax. @carpediumac or https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/examples/initialisation/server-side_processing.html

Comment: @chandu komati I just added more code to make my codes more readable. I have read the official documents but haven't found what I want

Answer (score 0):

I've found my answer.

I need to write a callback function that returns the data (array) which is found from my object.

Code:

```
table = $('#_table').dataTable({
                searching: false,
                paging: true,
                ajax: function (data, callback, settings) {
                    $.ajax({
                             type: "post",
                             url: '/test/getvalues',
                             dataType: "json",
                             success: function (result) {
                                var dataToUse = {};
                                dataToUse.data = result.map.count;
                                callback(dataToUse);
                             }
                           });
                  },
               columns: [
                 "data": "name",
                 "data": "count"
               ]
        })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
table = $('#_table').dataTable({
  searching: false,
  paging: true,
  ajax: function (data, callback, settings) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: '/test/getvalues',
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (result) {
         callback(result.map.count);
      }
    });
  },

  // Columns
  columns: [{
    title: "Name",
    name: "name",
  }, {
    title: "Count",
    name: "count"
  }]
});
```